# Django log reports are not getting in my gmail

Tags: python, django, logging

I am new to python and Django. I am trying log errors to my gmail whenever code breaks and i configured some settings.Here is the structure of my project:

```
MyProject:
-App1:
     ....
     views.py
-App2:
     ....
urls.py
settings.py
```

I like to log all messages into my gmail. Then I've setup in settings.py the following logger:

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'formatters': {
    'verbose': {
        'format' : "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s",
        'datefmt' : "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
    },
    'simple': {
        'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
    },
},
'handlers': {
    'file': {
        'level': 'WARNING',
        'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
        'filename': '_temp/logs/app.log',
        'formatter': 'verbose'
    },
    'mail_admins':{
        'level':'ERROR',
        'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
        'include_html': True,
    }
},
'loggers': {
    'django': {
        'handlers':['file'],
        'propagate': True,
        'level':'WARNING',
    },
    '_main': {
        'handlers': ['file'],
        'level': 'WARNING',
    },
    'apps.orders':{
        'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
         'level': 'ERROR',
         'propagate':False,
    },
    'apps.account':{
        'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
         'level': 'ERROR',
         'propagate':False,
    },
    'apps.vegetables':{
        'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
         'level': 'ERROR',
         'propagate':False,
    },
    'apps.utils':{
        'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
         'level': 'ERROR',
         'propagate':False,
    },
    'apps.rating':{
        'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
         'level': 'ERROR',
         'propagate':False,
    }
}
```

}

Here is my other settings in my settings.dev file

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'test@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password' 
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

SEND_BROKEN_LINK_EMAILS = True

ADMINS = (
   ('Administrator', 'navajyothms1989@gmail.com'),
   ('Administrator2','arunghosh@gmail.com'),
        )
MANAGERS = ADMINS
DEBUG = False
```

Is there any way out get error logs into email ??

Comment: Have you tested sending a plain email with Django? Just to make sure emails are working

Comment: Yes it is working.Using shell i can able to send email to mail admins